# Summing Consecutive Hourly Observation to find Maximums

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, summarize

I have data that looks like this...

```
Year   Month   Day   Hour  Total  Date       DateTime
1950   1       2     21    0.01   1/2/1950   1/2/1950 21:00
1950   1       2     23    0.01   1/2/1950   1/2/1950 23:00
1950   1       3     0     0.06   1/3/1950   1/3/1950 0:00
1950   1       3     1     0.01   1/3/1950   1/3/1950 1:00
1950   1       3     2     0.02   1/3/1950   1/3/1950 2:00
1950   1       4     11    0.24   1/4/1950   1/4/1950 11:00
1950   1       4     12    0.07   1/4/1950   1/4/1950 12:00
1950   1       4     15    0.10   1/4/1950   1/4/1950 15:00
1950   1       4     16    0.04   1/4/1950   1/4/1950 16:00
1950   1       4     17    0.01   1/4/1950   1/4/1950 17:00
```

and now I want to find the greatest two consecutive hour total (I'm also interested in the greatest consecutive three, four, five hour total). In the data above, the greatest two hour total would be 0.31 (summing observations six and seven). The greatest 3 hour total would be the last three observations. What's important is that the observations must been consecutive! If the observations are spread out by 5 hours but sum to a high total that is not important. I'm interested in the highest sum (from the total column) in consecutive observations (2 hour sums, 3 hour sums, 4 hour sums, etc.). What I'm shooting for is the greatest consecutive 2 hour or three hour total by year and month, with output that looks like this...

```
Year    Month    Two Hour Greatest
1950    1         0.31
1951    4         0.77
1952    3         0.91
1953    8         0.63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here are some sample data (made using tools from `lubridate`)

```
df <-
  tibble(
    date_time = seq(ymd_hm("1950-01-01 00:00")
                    , ymd_hm("1951-12-30 23:00")
                    , "1 hour")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Total = round(runif(n()), 2)
    , Year = year(date_time)
    , Month = month(date_time)
  )
```

Note that this assumes that you have an observation for every hour in the time period. If not, you may want to use `complete` from `tidyr` to add `0`'s (or another appropriate default) for the missing observations.

Then, use `rollsum` from `zoo` to calculate a rolling sum of the last `k` observations. Then, `summarise` to grab the max value for each window of interest.

Note that here I have used `group_by` *before* calculating the `rollsum` so that the summation does not cross month boundaries. That is, it is not calculating a total from the last hour of January and the first hour of February. This ensures that your maximum is only for observations that are *completely* within a given month. If you want something different, move the `group_by` step to *after* `rollsum` and ensure that you are happy with where `align` puts the result in `rollsum` (in the month of the last observation, in the example below).

The code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  mutate(
    two_hour_tot = rollsum(Total, k = 2, fill = NA, align = "right")
    , three_hour_tot = rollsum(Total, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right")
    , four_hour_tot = rollsum(Total, k = 4, fill = NA, align = "right")
  ) %>%
  summarise(
    two_hour_max = max(two_hour_tot, na.rm = TRUE)
    , three_hour_max = max(three_hour_tot, na.rm = TRUE)
    , four_hour_max = max(four_hour_tot, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 5
# Groups:   Year [?]
    Year Month two_hour_max three_hour_max four_hour_max
   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
 1  1950     1         1.98           2.76          3.43
 2  1950     2         1.96           2.68          3.57
 3  1950     3         1.96           2.91          3.65
 4  1950     4         1.98           2.91          3.7 
 5  1950     5         1.95           2.76          3.65
 6  1950     6         1.97           2.82          3.53
 7  1950     7         1.97           2.8           3.71
 8  1950     8         1.94           2.85          3.53
 9  1950     9         2.00           2.77          3.43
10  1950    10         1.93           2.82          3.7 
# … with 14 more rows
```

(Obviously, your randomized/actual values will be different)